# Two servers take down my network when I change their IP addresses

Tags: linux, networking

It seems to be when I have either of the 2 servers out of 3 plugged into the network my Internet times out when I ping it from another location. I have 5 static IP addresses on my network and below is some of the information on them.

> **Not In Use**
>
> ```
> .33
> ```
>
> **Vicibox 7 - Opensuse 10**
>
> ```
> .34
> ```
>
> **Web Server - Centos 6.5**
>
> ```
> .35
> ```
>
> **Data server - Ubuntu 12**
>
> ```
> .36
> ```
>
> **Computer Network**
>
> ```
> .37
> ```

---

### My Troubleshooting

I've been experiencing this issue since yesterday. Comcast wasn't able to help  me when I reached out to them so here are the steps that I took to pin point the issue troubleshooting on my own.

1. un-plugged everything from the modem
2. Plugged the computers back in (so far everything is working fine. Internet is great).
3. Plugged in the web server first and waited 15 minutes. (still working great)
4. Plugged in the opensuse server and waited 15 minutes. (started getting request timeouts and couldnt access the internet really.)
5. Unplugged opensuse server. (internet started working great again)
6. plugged in data server and waited 15 minutes (internet went to crap again)
7. unplugged the data server and internet was working great again

I pinpointed the 2 servers, but it just seems strange that 2 out of 3 servers would cause Internet connectivity issues. I also checked `iftop` and for the vici server asterisk `-rvvv` to see if there was any unusual traffic and nothing.

I am at a loss and come here with my detail to see if someone can help me get this resolved.

---

### Additional Detail

I did some hardware testing. I changed the NIC I was using to the second one. I tried it as DHCP and hooked into the router and the network was fine but as soon as I set that NIC to Static, the network started crashing again. I have rechecked my static configuration and it is all set correctly.

**Configuration when the network does not work**

[image]

**Configuration when the network works**

[image]

Comment: 1) ensure the ips and netmasks are unique and dont clash. 2) ensure the mac addresses on the interfaces are unique.

Comment: I did. I've been using them on this network for almost a month now. It just started happening yesterday around lunch.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on "my internet times out when I ping it from another location"? Are you saying the Internet dies when you begin pinging a server? Is it a specific server or any server? Does the Internet die on all devices? Does the Internet return to normal if you stop pinging? Or does pinging not matter, as the troubleshooting steps you laid out don't mention pinging at all?

Comment: Yes of course I can clarify. So it is just 2 out of the 3 servers. As soon as I plug one of them in my internet starts to be intermittent.  I can get to a page and then it just keeps loading or timeout with error. As far as pinging goes. I will ping from a home computer that is not on the network. It pings fine until I plug in one of the 2 servers then i can see it start to request time out

Comment: It seems you are trying to assign your static "public" IP addresses to your machines on the internal network and then have the ISP router/modem just deliver to those. You might want to check the ISP router settings and set those up to NAT to private IP address from whatever public address the traffic needs to go to. You are probably confusing your router plugging two subnets into the LAN crashing it causing Internet to be in accessible. I usually setup a firewall or router and configure it to route accordingly between the ISP router and the private LAN in this type of scenario.

Comment: I get that. But I have another server that is setup the same and when it is just that server the internet is fine. Plus it has been fine for the last couple weeks and big things changed.

Comment: Can you tell me the make and model of the ISP router by chance? I'll look up the guide on it real quick and see if it has anything that talks about this sort of configuration. I have a Comcast modem at this one small office I support from time to time and they too have a block of 5 IPs and I configured the ISP Comcast router as pass thru I think and then have a firewall appliance and some rules that routes that traffic back into their publicly accessible servers. Just tell me the make and model and I'll see if I can find anything to help you test and troubleshoot some more.

Comment: Also, you plug each server directly into the LAN ports of the ISP router, correct? I just want to be sure I understand the physical connections of the servers to this ISP modem/router so confirm that detail for me as well.

Comment: The comcast modem is Cisco Dpc 3939